I am getting a 200 OK on postman but in the Splunk Logs I am getting Data Insertion Failed and data not being inserted , why is this happening?
I have a database framework that I use as a package in another flask application . It has several files like db_framework.py (this is like the entry point , contains the functions that one can use by importing this package) , BiosCluster.py file that contains the table/model (its SQLAlchemy) and then there is utils.py that contains utility function like insert_data and insert_validated data .
Now I am trying to consume this package by importing it in my flask application and trying to use the methods inside it by creating an endpoint .
Now I am trying to insert some data , sending a POST request and the body ,I get a 200 OK in postman and in postman console as well that data is inserted successfully(this line is in the api.py code posted) BUT on the db side in the splunk logs I see "Data Insertion Failed"(this in one of the logger messages in the utils.py file that i have posted) . I am unable to figure out what's wrong
db_framework.py :
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pandas as pd
import logging
import datetime
from .bios_cluster import *
from . import utils

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s', filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
class DbPipeline():
    def __init__(self,engine):
        self.engine = engine
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
    def insert_to_cluster(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        table_name = BiosCluster
        df_json = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        is_data_valid = validate_insert_data_bios_cluster(df_json, table_name, self.session)
        utils.insert_validated_data(is_data_valid, self.session, table_name, df_json)

BiosCluster.py :
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, String, Text, Sequence, Float, BigInteger, create_engine, Boolean, func, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import sqlalchemy as db
import getpass
import logging
from . import constants
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
Base = declarative_base()
def get_current_user():
    return getpass.getuser()
class BiosCluster(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bios_cluster'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "something"}

    cluster_label_cd = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cluster_name = Column(String)
    cluster_display_name = Column(String)
    client_market = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean)
    created_dt = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    created_by = Column(String, default = get_current_user)
    updated_dt = Column(DateTime)
    updated_by = Column(String)

# Validate data to insert in Table
def validate_insert_data_bios_cluster(data, table_name, session):
    session = session()
    query = db.select([table_name])
    print(f'query is = {query}')
    bios_cluster_data = session.execute(query).fetchall()
    print(f'bios cluster data is printed successfully')
    # Check for cluster_label_cd unique primary key
    cluster_label_cd = [bios_cluster_row.cluster_label_cd for bios_cluster_row in bios_cluster_data]
    cluster_label_cd = set(cluster_label_cd)
    cluster_label_cd_to_insert = {dd['cluster_label_cd'] for dd in data}
    # Check for cluster name exist with the same name
    cluster_display_name = [
        bios_cluster_row.cluster_display_name
        for bios_cluster_row in bios_cluster_data if bios_cluster_row.is_active is True
        ]
    cluster_display_name = set(cluster_display_name)
    cluster_display_name_to_insert = {dd['cluster_display_name'] for dd in data}
    if cluster_label_cd_to_insert.isdisjoint(cluster_label_cd):
        if cluster_display_name_to_insert.isdisjoint(cluster_display_name):
            return True
        cluster_display_name_exist = cluster_display_name_to_insert.intersection(cluster_display_name)
        logger.error(f"Following cluster display name already exist in the DB: {cluster_display_name_exist}")
        return False
    cluster_label_cd_exist = cluster_label_cd_to_insert.intersection(cluster_label_cd)
    logger.error(f"Following cluster label cd are already exist : {cluster_label_cd_exist}")
    return False

utils.py:
from .bios_cluster import *

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def insert_data(session, table_name, data):
    data_inserted = False
    session = session()
    try:
        with session.begin():
            data_list = []
            for d in data:
                data_list.append(table_name(**d))
            session.add_all(data_list)
        session.commit()
        data_inserted = True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Data Insertion failed in table : {table_name} {e}")
    return data_inserted

def insert_validated_data(is_data_valid, session, table_name, df_json):
    if is_data_valid:
        is_data_inserted = insert_data(session, table_name, df_json)
        if is_data_inserted:
            logger.info(f"Data got inserted successfully in the table {table_name}")
        else:
            logger.error(f"Data insertion failed in the table : {table_name}")
    else:
        logger.error(f"Some mismatch in the input data of {table_name}")

this is the api i am trying to use to access the functionalities and utilities of this package , api.py
@restAPI.route("/api/biosdbfw",methods=['POST','PUT'])
def biosdbfw_operations():
   import pandas as pd
   # db_object = DbPipeline()
   try:
      logger.info("bios accessed")
      engine = get_scheduling_db_engine()
      db_object = DbPipeline(engine=engine)
      # db_object.engine = engine.connect()
      logger.info("DB connection line passed")
      data = request.json
      print(data)
      logger.info("Data Printed")
      operation = request.args.get('operation')
      print(operation)
      if operation == 'insertToBiosCluster':
         df = pd.DataFrame([data])
         db_object.insert_to_cluster(df)
         logger.info("Data Inserted...")
         return Response(json.dumps("Data Inserted into bios_cluster successfully "), status=200, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
       return Response(json.dumps("Invalid Operation"), status=400, mimetype="application/json")
         # return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid operation'}),400
   except Exception as e:
      logger.exception(str(e))
      return Response(json.dumps("Internal Server Error Occured"), status=500, mimetype="application/json")


Traceback :
2024-04-05 21:45:46,306 - rit.views.rest_api - Line 325 -  INFO :  bios accessed
2024-04-05 21:45:46,307 - rit.views.rest_api - Line 329 -  INFO :  DB connection line passed
{'cluster_label_cd': 200510, 'cluster_name': 'Test Cluster 1', 'cluster_display_name': 'Test Cluster Display 1', 'client_market': 'Test Market 1', 'is_active': True}
2024-04-05 21:45:46,307 - rit.views.rest_api - Line 332 -  INFO :  Data Printed
insertToSmartbiosCluster
query is = SELECT ritadm.smartbios_cluster.cluster_label_cd, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.cluster_name, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.cluster_display_name, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.client_market, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.is_active, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.created_dt, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.created_by, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.updated_dt, ritadm.smartbios_cluster.updated_by
FROM ritadm.smartbios_cluster
smartbios cluster data is printed successfully
2024-04-05 21:45:46,345 - mlslib.smartbiosdb_framework.utils - Line 23 -  ERROR :  A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlslib/smartbiosdb_framework/utils.py", line 15, in insert_data
    with session.begin():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 949, in begin
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.
2024-04-05 21:45:46,346 - mlslib.smartbiosdb_framework.utils - Line 24 -  ERROR :  Data Insertion failed in table : <class 'mlslib.smartbiosdb_framework.smartbios_cluster.SmartbiosCluster'> A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.
2024-04-05 21:45:46,346 - mlslib.smartbiosdb_framework.utils - Line 47 -  ERROR :  Data insertion failed in the table : <class 'mlslib.smartbiosdb_framework.smartbios_cluster.SmartbiosCluster'>
2024-04-05 21:45:46,346 - rit.views.rest_api - Line 338 -  INFO :  Data Inserted...
2024-04-05 21:45:46,397 - rit.services.TrackingServices - Line 31 -  DEBUG :  Initiating Match services class
2024-04-05 21:45:46,397 - rit.db.RITActionsLog - Line 25 -  INFO :  Initializing RIT Actions Log class
2024-04-05 21:45:46,400 - rit.db.RITActionsLog - Line 49 -  DEBUG :  RIT Actions Log table for user actions initialized
2024-04-05 21:45:46,788 - rit.db.RITActionsLog - Line 81 -  DEBUG :  Tracking row inserted

smartbios/bios etc is the same thing . you can ignore the table names and stuff . i tried just to mask somethings

Firstly, I don't see any functions named as insert_to_bios_cluster. Second, please include the flask output and exception logs. Postman result or output has nothing to do with your application.

@BcK added the traceback , looking at the traceback its the line with session.begin() causing the error in utils.py


sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun.

should give you enough information. You are trying to open a session when there's already one at your disposal.
I suggest you research sqlalchemy a bit more before using session.begin and session overall. Better yet, use flask-sqlalchemy if you are not ready to put that effort into learning it.
Removing the with session.begin() should fix your problem.
def insert_data(session, table_name, data):
    data_inserted = False
    session = session()
    try:
        data_list = []
        for d in data:
            data_list.append(table_name(**d))
        session.add_all(data_list)
        session.commit()
        data_inserted = True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Data Insertion failed in table : {table_name} {e}")
    return data_inserted


cool , i will try this and let you know asap

I think it worked but still i get that error called data insertion failed and also pscopg2 privilege access error , i only have read access given to me by the admin so is it occuring because of that ?

well you have your answer. you can mark the question as solved and create another question if you are still having problems.
